# How to calculate the correct size of a loopback device filesystem image for debootstrap?

Tags: disk-usage, ext4, dd, loop-device, debootstrap

I'm using debootstrap to create a rootfs for a device that I want to then write to an image file.  To calculate the size needed from my rootfs, I do the following:

```
local SIZE_NEEDED=$(du -sb $CHROOT_DIR|awk '{print $1}')
SIZE_NEEDED=$(($SIZE_NEEDED / 1048576 + 50)) # in MB + 50 MB space
dd if=/dev/zero of=$ROOTFS_IMAGE bs=1M count=$SIZE_NEEDED
```

As you can see I'm leaving 50MB of padding beyond what `dd` calculates I need.

I then create the loopback device, create a partition table and filesystem:

```
LO_DEVICE=$(losetup --show -f $ROOTFS_IMAGE)
parted $LO_DEVICE mktable msdos mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
partprobe $LO_DEVICE
local LO_ROOTFS_PARTITION="${LO_DEVICE}p1"
mkfs.ext4 -O ^64bit $LO_ROOTFS_PARTITION
```

It seems `parted` attempts to do some sector alignment (?) as the partition doesn't quite take up the whole virtual disk, but close enough.

I then mount the new partition and start writing files.  But then I run out of disk space right near the end!

```
mount $LO_ROOTFS_PARTITION $LO_MOUNT_POINT
cp -rp $CHROOT_DIR/* $LO_MOUNT_POINT

.....
cp: cannot create directory '/root/buildimage/rootfs_mount/var': No space left on device
```

I suspect this is some block size conversion issue or maybe difference between MiB and MB? Because up to a certain image size, it seems that I have enough headroom with the 50MB of padding.  (I want *some* free space in the image by default, but not a lot.)  The image size isn't off by a factor-of-two so there's some creep or overhead that gets magnified as the image size gets larger and I'm not sure where it's coming from.

For context, here's the last one I did that doesn't fit:

```
# du -sb build/rootfs
489889774   build/rootfs
```

Ok, 489MB/1024**2 + 50MB = 517MB image size.  So `dd` looked like:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=build/rootfs.img size=1M count=517
517+0 records in
517+0 records out
542113792 bytes (542 MB, 517 MiB) copied, 2.02757 s, 267 MB/s
```

Confirmed on disk it looks slightly larger:

```
# du -sb build/rootfs.img
542113792   build/rootfs.img
```

The partition looks like:

```
# parted /dev/loop0 print
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 542MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  542MB  541MB  primary  ext4
```

and mounted filesystem:

```
# df -h /dev/loop0p1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0p1    492M  482M     0 100% /root/buildimage/build/rootfs_mount
```

So maybe there is overhead in the ext4 filesystem, possibly for superblocks/ journal/ etc?  How can I account for that in my size calculation?

**EDIT:**

Looking into ext4 overhead such as [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/282317/disk-space-overhead-in-ext4).

Also looking into [mkfs.ext4 options](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) such as `-m` (reserved) and various journaling and inode options.  In general if I know there's a 5% overhead coming from the filesystem, I can factor that in easily enough.

**EDIT #2:**

Thinking that `du` might be under-reporting actual on-disk size requirements (e.g. a 10-byte file still takes up a 4k block,  right?) I tried a few other options:

```
# du -sb build/rootfs        # This is what I was using
489889774   build/rootfs

# du -sm build/rootfs        # bigger
527 build/rootfs

# du -sk build/rootfs        # bigger-est
539088  build/rootfs
```

Furthermore, the manpage for `-b` notes that it's an alias for `--apparent-size` which can be smaller than "actual disk usage."  So that may be (most) of where my math was wrong.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/246835/convert-directory-to-qemu-kvm-virtual-disk-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly the simplest solution is to heavily overprovision the space initially, copy all the files, then use `resize2fs -M` to reduce the size to the minimum this utility can manage. Here's an example:

```
dir=/home/meuh/some/dir
rm -f /tmp/image
size=$(du -sb $dir/ | awk '{print $1*2}')
truncate -s $size /tmp/image
mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -O ^64bit /tmp/image
sudo mount /tmp/image /mnt/loop
sudo chown $USER /mnt/loop
rsync -a $dir/ /mnt/loop
sync
df /mnt/loop
sudo umount /mnt/loop
e2fsck -f /tmp/image 
resize2fs -M /tmp/image 
newsize=$(e2fsck -n /tmp/image | awk -F/ '/blocks$/{print $NF*1024}')
truncate -s $newsize /tmp/image
sudo mount /tmp/image /mnt/loop
df /mnt/loop
diff -r $dir/ /mnt/loop
sudo umount /mnt/loop
```

Some excerpts from the output for an example directory:

```
+ size=13354874
Creating filesystem with 13040 1k blocks and 3264 inodes
+ df /mnt/loop
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1         11599  7124      4215  63% /mnt/loop
+ resize2fs -M /tmp/image
Resizing the filesystem on /tmp/image to 8832 (1k) blocks.
+ newsize=9043968
+ truncate -s 9043968 /tmp/image
+ df /mnt/loop
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1          7391  7124        91  99% /mnt/loop
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had considered that but wasn't sure how to shrink it down afterwards.  What about a whole-disk image that include a partition table?  You can resize the filesystem but then I guess you would need to use `parted` to resize the partition too before truncating.

Comment: Yes, but of course you could just stop at the resize result, throw everything away, and start again with your original code and this new target size.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I've changed my original code to use `du -sm` which seems to have resolved my issue.  I think the crux of the problem was the fact that `-sb` is an alias for `--apparent-size`.

Furthermore, knowing that ext4 requires, say 5% overhead makes it easy enough to factor into the calculation but I don't think that was the actual issue at hand since it was failing while writing as superuser.